# nmap to scan specific ports on specific list of IPs

Tags: linux, bash, networking, ip, nmap

I am using [nmap](https://nmap.org/) to scan all open ports on all IPs connected with local network.

I want to check specific ports on a list of IPs which is being picked from a text file.

Is it possible to specify a list of ports along with a list of IPs?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
nmap (specfic ports) -sS -iL ip_list.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-p`:

```
nmap -p80,443 -sS -iL ip_list.txt
```

From [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap):

> -p : Only scan specified ports
> Ex: -p22; -p1-65535; -p U:53,111,137,T:21-25,80,139,8080,S:9

If you just want the open ports, you can add `--open`:

```
nmap -p80,443 --open -sS -iL ip_list.txt
```